# Wordpress redwaves-lite theme Comments Quote remove

Tags: themes

I use a free wordpress template (redwaves-lite) , it is a very nice theme but  has a small bug , if there is a large number of comment with quote , It looks bad , here is the picture :

https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-sLBXWHBoZ0Q/WUB0lMGiYTI/AAAAAAAA8bk/7wK-cIbHUWkPujgr9MePIhg31jjGJV-egCLcBGAs/s1600/11462.jpg

How can I remove comment - Quote

mobile view It looks bad:http://www.ceofix.com/1434/facebook-hesabiniz-kapatildi-ve-kimlik-mi-istiyor/comment-page-9/#comments

Comments just want to remove "comment quote" or want to change comment quote styl :